# Skip_log_bin and innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

Tags: mariadb, environment-variables

If I have `skip_log_bin =1` is there any reason for not having `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0`?

If I have understand correctly, `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`, reads data from log file and stores them to disk in a way according to its value.

So if I am not using log (`skip_log_bin=1`) why should I have value other from 0 on  `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those refer to different logs.

The binlog (`log_bin`) is for replication and other purposes for capturing writes *outside* of the server.

The other log controls how securely a "pull-the-plug" crash can be recovered from.  `=1` performs an extra write to make crashes 100% recoverable.  `=0`, or slightly better `=2` have less overhead but are "good enough" for many applications.